# Gmail account authentication error while sending mail in android application

Tags: java, android, gmail

I am getting following error when i am trying to send message from android application with gmailapi. 
**"Could not connect to SMTP host: relay.jangosmtp.net, port: 465, response: -1"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 2015 google is not allowing "less secure apps" to connect through their SMTP port (this means you need a ssl or tls certificate).

To allow them you could try this: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en